# SQL - How to solve this query?

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to figure out how to solve this query.

**Select candidates who have worked for IBM and for Microsoft.**

The tables associated with the database includes

```
Candidate(Id,Name)
Company(Id,Name)
hasWorkedFor(CandidateId,CompanyId)
```

Where CandidateId and Company Id are foreign keys to the Candidate table and Company table.

The query which I got was:

```
SELECT Candidate.Name 
FROM Candidate x, Candidate y, Company c1, Company c2, hasWorkedFor 
WHERE x.Id = Id 
  AND c1.Id = CompanyId
  AND c1.Name = "Microsoft" 
  AND c2.Id = CompanyId  
  AND c2.Name = "IBM";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  And -- on the topic of doing things right -- *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Candidate.* from Candidate inner join (
    select CandidateId from hasWorkedFor inner join Company
    on hasWorkedFor.CompanyId = Company.id
    where Company.name in ('IBM', 'Microsoft')
    group by CandidateId
    having count(distinct CompanyId) = 2
)t
on Candidate.Id = t.CandidateId
```

Note, that this query also gives those candidates, which may worked for another companies *also*.

If you need candidates, which worked **only** for IBM and Microsoft, then you can use:

```
select Candidate.* from Candidate inner join (
    select t1.CandidateId from (
        select CandidateId   from hasWorkedFor inner join Company
        on hasWorkedFor.CompanyId = Company.id
        where Company.name in ('IBM', 'Microsoft')
        group by CandidateId
        having count(distinct CompanyId) = 2
    )t1 inner join(
        select CandidateId from hasWorkedFor 
        inner join Company
        on hasWorkedFor.CompanyId = Company.id
        group by CandidateId
        having count( distinct CompanyId ) = 2
    ) t2 on t1.CandidateId = t2.CandidateId
)t
on Candidate.Id = t.CandidateId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and let me know in case of any queries.

```
select a.name as candiate_name
from
   candidate a
left join
   hasworkedfor b
on a.id = b.candidateid
left join
   company c
on b.companyid = c.id
where c.name = 'Microsoft' and c.name  = 'IBM';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select candidate.name from candidate 
inner join hasworkedfor 
on candidate.id = hasworkedfor .candidateid inner join company 
on hasworkedfor .companyid = company.id 
where company.name = 'Microsoft' and company.name  = 'IBM'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ca.Name FROM Candidate ca 
    WHERE ca.Id IN (SELECT hw.CandidateId FROM hasWorkedFor hw 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Company co ON hw.CompanyId = co.Id WHERE co.Name = 'Microsoft') AND
          ca.Id IN (SELECT hw.CandidateId FROM hasWorkedFor hw 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Company co ON hw.CompanyId = co.Id WHERE co.Name = 'IBM')
```

or

```
SELECT ca.Name FROM Candidate ca 
    WHERE COUNT(SELECT DISTINCT hw.CompanyId FROM hasWorkedFor hw 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Company co ON hw.CompanyId = co.Id 
                        WHERE (co.Name = 'Microsoft' OR co.Name = 'IBM') AND hw.CandidateId = ca.Id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Candidate c where
exists(select * from hasWorkedFor w where w.CandidateId=c.Id and w.CompanyId = 'Microsoft')
and exists(select * from hasWorkedFor w where w.CandidateId=c.Id and w.CompanyId = 'IBM')
```

In other words, select from Candidate where

- there exists an entry of him working in MSFT and
- there exists an entry of him working in IBM

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
SELECT ca.Name
FROM Company cm
JOIN hasWorkedFor wk ON cm.Id = wk.CompanyId
JOIN Candidate ca ON wk.CandidateId = ca.Id
WHERE cm.Name IN ('IBM', 'Microsoft')
GROUP BY ca.Id,ca.Name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```